# simple way to hide entire table column? (rendered only when php if condition true)

Tags: php, html, laravel, permissions

I am currently working on a laravel project which involves permissions. This is my first time handling permission. In the app, certain users without permission cannot see some columns in a table. What I did is

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col A</th>
            <th>Col B</th>
            @if(has permission)
            <th>Col C</th>
            @endif
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(....)
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        @if(has permission)
        <td>C</td>
        @endif
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I just find this is kind of stupid? the code is lengthy and hard to maintain I am thinking of a better way to handle this.

Comment: Will there be multiple "permissions" or only one.

Comment: do you mean the number of html blocks asking for permission?

Comment: Kind of yes, but I mean is it only to differentiate admin and basic user?

Comment: Yes, there will be multiple blocks required this, and sorry i dont quite get what you mean to differentiate admin and basic user,

Comment: Do not worry about it. What I would do (and do in most of the projects), is leverage blade directive [`@can('action', resource::class)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#via-blade-templates) and policies this way its pretty easy to understand the view.

Comment: yes, my mistake, i should use can directive or whatever related to permissions, but may i know if this piece of html code good? or can be improved?

Comment: Yes it is good.

Comment: I mean the way to hide a column in a html table, sorry, question not clear

Comment: Next time try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :) have fun.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: @Kyslik No, this is not a suitable question for Code Review.  See their help center and meta as to why before recommending migration.

Comment: @syb0rg interesting, right from first example what not to ask :D, thanks. I guess with better wording and different code example it might fit the rules but its all subjective.